# AWS Cognito SES FROM E-mail address only verified e-mail address allowed no verified domains

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-ses

I'm currently trying to setup an AWS Cognito User Pool. I have already verified my domain through SES but I can't enter an e-mail address from my verified domain. Only specific verified email addresses are allowed to select from the dropdown.

Can someone explain how I can change this?